# to_datetime won't recognize dates '20 Oct 2015' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a code extracting dates in multiple formats. I then used pd.to_datetime to convert the strings for sorting. However, it's not changing the middle column of dates.

```
x = dates[0].str.extract(r'(\d{1,2}?[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4})|((?:\d{1,2} )?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[-., ]*(?:\d{1,2})?[rd|st|th|nd]?[,]?[- ]\d{4})|(\d{4})') 

#reformat dates 
x[0] = pd.to_datetime(x[0],infer_datetime_format=True)
x[1] = pd.to_datetime(x[1],exact=False,errors = 'ignore')
x[2] = pd.to_datetime(x[2],infer_datetime_format=True,errors = 'coerce' )
#sort
#return the index column 
y = pd.Series(x.sort_values(by=[0, 1,2]).index)
```

This returns the middle column as is, without the dates altered.

[Here is a screen shot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmxIK.png)

I inspected the data and tried multiple dates of various formats and they all work individually. Is the problem that the dates in the column are of different formats--some with day first, some with day second etc?

[Here is a screen shot of the data in the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO77l.png)

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(['20 Oct 2015'])` works perfectly fine on my system.

Comment: yeah, mine too. I'm getting 'unknown string format' error for that column when I run it without additional parameters.

Comment: I checked it out more and updated my question.

Comment: IT'S A SPELLING MISTAKE

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the str-to-date format correctly. To convert "20 Oct 2015" use the following:

```
pd.to_datetime("20 Oct 2015", format='%d %b %Y')
```

It will return:

```
Timestamp('2015-10-20 00:00:00')
```

A list of time-formatting directives are here: http://strftime.org/